# Haar functions question and sequence of partial sums.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for an integrable function $f$ we define $$S_{n}(f) = \sum_{j = 0}^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{j}-1}<f,h_{j,k}>h_{j,k}.$$
Prove that if $f \in C([0,1])$, then $S_{n}(f)$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried the standard measure theoretic way of proving such statements: starting with characteristic functions, then checking what happens when $f$ ist just a simple function, finally extending the results to continuous functions?

Comment: What are these $h_{i,k}$? If they are all 0 the statement is wrong.

Comment: In general, $$h_{j,k}(t) = 2^{j/2} h(2^j t-k)$$ where $h(t)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2)}(t)-\mathbb{1}_{[1/2,1)}(t)$ and $j$ and $k$ are any integers. Although, to ensure that the wavelets are supported on $[0,1)$ you need $0\leq k\leq 2^j-1$ and $j\geq 0$.

Comment: @yanko  they are Haar functions

Comment: @Santiago  No I have not tried this approach ..... but is there a book that follows this approach that you recommend for me ?